# Delete button with dialogOK in Grid

Tags: grid, atk4

Im trying to implement delete button in GRID, same as with CRUD. I found dialogOK (http://agiletoolkit.org/blog/introduction-to-dialog-integration/), but guess i don't know how to use it right.

My code:

```
$gridC=$this->add('Grid');
$gridC->setModel('Campaign');
$gridC->addcolumn('Button', 'Delete')->js('click', $this->js()->univ()->dialogOK('Yey','Some custom javascript action here',$this->delete()));

//test only
$gridC->addcolumn('Button', 'Deletex')->js('click')->univ()->dialogOK('Are you sure?','This will take you to other page',$this->js()->univ()->page($this->api->getDestinationURL('admin')));

...

function delete(){
  ...
}
```

When i click on the button the delete() function starts right away, before i click ok. Also modal window is started :(

Any suggestions, i searched but couldn't find any good example..

NEXT DAY:

I checked the thing again, im almost shure i did it the right way, but i think i found a bug i dialogOK (http://agiletoolkit.org/blog/introduction-to-dialog-integration/)

I i re-create this example on any normal page:

```
$button = $this->add('Button');
$button->js('click')->univ()->dialogOK('Are you sure?','This will take you to other page',
  $button->js()->univ()->page($this->api->getDestinationURL('index'))
);
```

The page redirects to index page, it doen't wait for OK button clicked. Insted it opens the dialogOK, but in the background redirects to index page..

I'm using atk 4.2.5 from master branch..

Comment: I think this dialogOK is buggy, even the example from this page doesn't work: http://agiletoolkit.org/blog/introduction-to-dialog-integration/

Answer (score 0):

OK, that webpage has some bugs :( I would really appreciate if you could edit it and send in pull request in Github atk4-web.

Some tips to get you on road:

- Try to use dialogConfirm() method not dialogOK(). Is it working then?
- Try to add ->_enclose() after ->page(). That'll enclose JS expression in function.
- If dialogConfirm() works and similar dialogOK() does not work, then I guess there is small bug in dialogOK() method. There should be `close: if(fn)fn(),` instead of `close: fn,` in atk4_univ.js file dialogOK method.

Can you try these tips and tell me what works for you? Sorry I didn't do that myself - I'm really out of time now :(